# Why can't I access newly created records in Hibernate/Struts?

Tags: java, mysql, exception, struts

So I have this JS form that creates a new record (`MySQL`, `Struts`, `Hibernate`) via an AJAX request.

Once the record is created, I then return the new ID.  At that point, I take that ID and append it to the URL and navigate to an edit screen.

Well, sometimes, I'm getting an `IORecordNotFoundException` and/or `java.lang.NullPointerException' errors on the edit screen.

If I give it a second or two, the records loads just fine.  The MySQL server is a little busy at about 19.8 commands per second on average.

Any suggestions on how to better handle this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: If you get an ID back when it's being created, the item should be in the DB. Are you running in a clustered environment, server or DB? Sharding? Without more info it'll be tough to help, but it sounds like something is going on behind-the-scenes.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking.  The record is there (as per the ID).  It's almost like I can't load it yet because the DB needs time to "settle down".  No, no clustering, sharding, etc.

Comment: Doing anything interesting/unusual with caching? If not, I don't really see how this is possible.

Comment: Well, *something* weird is going on, because there's no "settling down" time ;) If you can create a short, self-contained example it might help diagnose.

Comment: OK, just noticed this.  I updated the record via an AJAX post (changed 0 to 1).  When the page loaded, it showed 0.  When I pressed F5, it showed 1.  I wonder if there is some strange caching going on?

Comment: It's probably not too strange ;) Do you set all the caching headers to force no-caching?

Comment: How are you handling transaction scope?  Are you manually committing or letting the framework do it?  May be possible the ajax is returning before the DB transaction commits.

Comment: If you are getting a NPE, the stacktrace would be vital to diagnose the errors.

Comment: As Affe mentioned, it sounds like you may be starting a transaction, but not committing it. If you are using a pooled datasource, the transaction may be getting committed somewhere else, like when the connection is eventually returned to the pool. Or, a subsequent select statement on the connection may cause the transaction to commit. Take a careful look at your transaction boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not committing your hibernate transaction immediately,
the previous transaction is committed only when the next transaction is started.So try explicity committing the transaction.

```
tx.commit()
```